# How to correctly call base class methods (and constructor) from inherited classes in Python?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a `Base` class and a `Child` class that inherits from `Base`. What is the right way to call the constructor of base class from a child class in Python? Do I use `super`?

Here is an example of what I have so far:

```
class Base(object):
   def __init__(self, value):
       self.value = value
   ...

class Child(Base):
   def __init__(self, something_else):
       super(Child, self).__init__(value=20)
       self.something_else = something_else
   ...
```

Is this correct?

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Comment: Ignacio, I tested it, but there are other ways, for example, in `Child`, I could do `def __init__(self, something_else): Base.__init__(value=20)` and I have no idea if I can do that or not... Therefore I asked to know how to do it absolutely correctly and in a modern Python way.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

That is correct.  Note that you can also call the `__init__` method directly on the `Base` class, like so:

```
class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self, something_else):
        Base.__init__(self, value = 20)
        self.something_else = something_else
```

That's the way I generally do it.  But it's discouraged, because it doesn't behave very well in the presence of multiple inheritance.  Of course, multiple inheritance has all sorts of odd effects of its own, and so I avoid it like the plague.

In general, if the classes you're inheriting from use `super`, you need to as well.

Comment: Thanks for describing both methods. I was unsure about the `Base.__init__` one.

Comment: Can you add another argument other than "value" to the example?  Does order matter?  What if value is being assigned to value?

Comment: what about in python 3.9?

Comment: what if I want to call a super from super? Can I do something like `super(BaseBase, self).__init__(value)`?

Answer (score 71):

If you're using Python 3.1, super is new and improved. It figures out the class and instance arguments for you. So you should call super without arguments:

```
class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self, value, something_else):
        super().__init__(value)
        self.something_else = something_else
    ...
```

Comment: what if I want to call a super from super? Can I do something like `super(BaseBase, self).__init__(value)`?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, that's correct. If you wanted to be able to pass `value` into the `Child` class you could do it this way

```
class Child(Base):
   def __init__(self, value, something_else):
       super(Child, self).__init__(value)
       self.something_else = something_else
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for illustrating how to pass value to Child and then this value to Base!

Comment: You also need to make sure that all of the superclasses of Child can accept that value, and pass it on, since in general, you can't be certain that Base is the next one called.

Comment: what if I want to call a super from super? Can I do something like `super(BaseBase, self).__init__(value)`?